# Video background showing but not playing on firefox for android

Tags: android, firefox, html5-video, firefox-android

I encountered a problem while trying to use a background video on mobile. Everything works just fine on Chrome and Opera but whenever I try to open the webpage on firefox for android it won't start. It's there but autoplay won't start for some reasons. Can you help me figure out why?

```
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted loop>
          <source src="images/ECLYPSODark_Side.mp4" type=video/mp4>
          <source src="images/ECLYPSODark_Side.ogv" type=video/ogg>
          <source src="images/ECLYPSODark_Side.webm" type=video/webm>
    </video>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue...

Comment: let's hope someone finds a way to help us!

Comment: any solution found for this issue @Rubis, @CamHart?

Comment: I never found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to it. If you put the video on mute it autoplays, otherwise it doesn't!